# iTunes Connect App Update release for all countries?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I just released an app update in itunes connect. But I want to make it available for all users in the world but the app itself on the App Store should be limited, for example just USA und Canada.

So the update should be available for all but specific territories shouldn't be able to download the app the first time.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks so much in advance
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the countries where you want it to be available in iTunes Connect. This way people in those countries will be able to download the app regardless of whether it's an update or it's their first time downloading it.

There's no way to limit the update just to some countries. For example, let's say the first version of your app is available in just USA. Then you want the update to be available in USA and Canada. How would people in Canada update if they never had access to the first version of your app? The only option is to enable it in Canada for new customers as well as existing customers.

Comment: Does updated app appear in "New section" in newly listed/added countries?

Comment: If Apple decided to do that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you can have access to one version at a time on `iTunes Connect`. When new version has been approved, you lose settings you made for the old release. So if you now want to release your new version/upgrade worldwide and your app's first version was intended to be release just in USA and Canada, new settings will be overridden. You cannot set things specifically for a version on iTunes connect. So new version will be accessible on worldwide app stores, where as the old version will no longer be accessible on iTunes. You cannot do anything for the old version after the release of new one.